# The error I get Which checking Apache Pig Version "Error: Could not find or load main class C:\java\lib\tools.jar"

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, command-prompt

I have my java working properly and also the environment variable is also set for java jdk 1.8.0_261
But when I run the `pig -version` its shows `Error: Could not find or load main class C:\java\lib\tools.jar`.

[image: Apache pig error]

I have also checked the java folder in lib for **tools.jar** and it is there.

[image: tool.jar]

Also the Apache Pig configuration is also correct in pig.cmd

[image: pig.cmd]

My Hadoop and MapReduce all are working fine with no error.

Comment: Look like you have manually editted `pig.cmd` to add the `C:\hadoop-3.3.0` paths. You shouldnt do that. You would instead add `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to your PATH

Answer (score 0):

Your installation is broken, or you have messed up a shell script. That error cannot really mean anything else.

When invoking `java.exe`, you can either pass a jar file, via `java -jar C:\foo.jar`, or a classpath + fully qualified class name: `java -cp C:\foo.jar;C:\bar.jar com.foo.fullyqualified.ClassName`.

That error means you've passed `C:\java\lib\tools.jar` in the position of that classname. That will fail to run on any system and regardless of installations: `C:\java\lib\tools.jar` is a file path, not a fully qualified class name. That `tools.jar` exists in that location is immaterial: It's as if I told you: "I searched for the book titled "Can of Paint" on your bookshelf and I can't find it", and you going: "That's bizarre, because (pointing at the cans of paint on the shelf in the garage), there are cans of paint right here". Java isn't treating that as a path to look up; it is treating it as a class name to search for on the classpath.

Note that this trivial invocation:

```
java.exe C:\lib\tools.jar
```

produces the exact error you are observing and that is the correct behaviour of java (because the right way to run it is either `java -jar C:\lib\tools.jar` or more likely `java -cp C:\lib\tools.jar;. com.foo.YourApp`. The fix is to.. not invoke java incorrectly like this.

### Reasons

1. Perhaps pig.cmd is broken. The image you pasted does not include the actual call to java.
2. Perhaps java is broken. Does `java.exe` work at all? Make some test file, compile it, run it. Does that work?
3. Perhaps the script is trying to start the jar by letting windows do it (so, double clicking it, or in a script, `start foo.jar`, which will then end up checking the HKLM registry section for `.jar`, and then checking the key there for how to start it, and if you've manually edited that, that would break things: You then presumably set it for e.g. `java %1` which is broken (it'd have to be `java -jar %1`).
4. `pig -version` doesn't invoke the pig.cmd you think it invokes, but something else.
5. Something in pig.cmd starts another script. Then that script is broken, or isnt the script pig.cmd thought it was, etc.